How to fix overlapped mesh that created by the add-on Blender GIS
I did the 3d map extrusion with the Blender GIS add-on. However, there are meshes overlapped and appeared pure black in cycle render. I tried to fix the mesh but seems like the meshes that created by this add-on are not able to remesh.
Eevee doesn't have the overlap problem but only cycle does.
Appreciate it if someone knows the solution... I have been stuck for a while

You could try using a proportional editing set to random and a huge radius area and move an object slightly to not trigger z fighting

or use that kind of setup https://i.sstatic.net/pBZsERkf.png

Thanks for the reply!
I tried the first one and that works!
But when I tried the setup, its still the same.
